# Capturing output of wmic queries run on remote machines via PSexec and python script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, psexec, wmic

I am attempting to use WMIC to return information on remote machines e.g software installed, configuration et.c and I'm using PSexec to run the tools remotely.

When I run a command such as

```
psexec \\hostname wmic product get name,version >> C:\Results.txt
```

from the command prompt I get a text file with the desired results.

As I have 200-300 machines to query and I need to run queries on a monthly basis I'd like to automate the process using a python 3.x script.

My problem is when I run this

```
import subprocess

cmdstr = r"psexec \\hostname wmic product get name,version >> C:\Results.txt"
result = subprocess.Popen(cmdstr, shell=True)
```

or

```
import subprocess

cmdstr = r"psexec \\hostname wmic product get name,version"
result = subprocess.Popen(cmdstr, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output= result.communicate()

print(output)
```

All I get the PStools copyright statement and output confirming it's running and exited with code 0 but no output from the WMIC query.

Ideally I want to be able to use the second example above so I can loop over all the machines and capture the output in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your psexec command.
-accepteula     This flag suppresses the display of the license dialog.